# Javascript/jquery: Cleaning up after once-executed script tags

Tags: jquery, long-polling

I have a page which uses the long-polling technique to get data back from the server in parts, creating script tags containing IIFE expressions, that will look something like this:

```
<script>
  (function(){ 
      $("#blah").append("Some new data");
  })();
</script>
```

If I get a LOT of these excess `<script>` tags, especially if the New Data is relatively large, I'm worried that it's going to start slowing down the page.
Would there be any performance benefit removing the script tag from the DOM after it has executed?

```
<script id="thescript">
  (function(){ 
      $("#blah").append("Some new data");
  })();
  $("#thescript").remove();
</script>
```

**EDIT:** I feel like this question has become a trainwreck and the intention was unclear. Apologies. Really ultimately looking for the answer to a different question and this is one misguided step along the way.

Comment: why can't you have external JS files with all this code?

Comment: Cant you just longpoll and then ajax the response into the current dom?

Comment: I'm getting a large (unknown-sized, really) amount of data from a PHP script. Using long-polling which creates mini script tags as the PHP gets data was one way to handle it without blowing up the browser.  Maybe I am mis-understanding long-polling, which is certainly a possibility.

Comment: Even IE6 can live with big js Objects and Arrays. But remember that the browser will have to render all the content and usually this will kill performance much faster.

Comment: Floyd: I've tried a "brain-dead ajax" version of my script, getting all data at once, and with about a megabyte of text coming back from the server my whole browser locked up. Looking for solutions. Maybe this question is barking up the wrong tree.

Comment: is it just a bunch of append to divs statements? I think AJAX call will definitely have a better performance. Honestly, having a MB of text getting added to the page is not a good idea in the first place :)

Comment: It's essentially creating a table of results from a database call, and I don't control the database engine. It returns all or nothing, and "all" could be a megabyte or more of text. I have no choice in the size of the response data.

Comment: What about paging? Blog engines like blogspot do not even use a COUNT() for performance reasons.

Comment: Server doesn't support paging of the data. I'd have to create a cache in between, which is more complex than the project deserves.

Comment: But this question isn't really about an analysis of the project. Going off on a real tangent here. I just want to know if removing the script tag from the DOM actually does something beneficial or not.

Comment: (What I would really like to do is retrieve the responseText of the XHR object as it comes in, while streaming. But allegedly this doesn't work anymore. So long-polling was my next option)

Comment: In fact I just added a bounty to my not-canonically-answered question along those original lines http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7740646/jquery-ajax-read-the-stream-incrementally

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could instead just return JavaScript and use jQuery's `$.getScript()` method.

Edit:

Maybe this would be a more direct answer.

If you request the script as plain text, you can then append it to the head and remove it.

```
$.get(url,function(str){
  var head = $("head"),
      script = $(str);
  head.append(str);
  str.remove();
},"text");
```

I haven't actually tried this, so I'm not 100% sure that it would work. It does sound logical though.

Another option would be to load the script into a particular element, then empty the element. It should have the same effect.

Edit Again: you could stick the script tags inside of a particular element with a class, then remove that element on success of the ajax call since you are returning more than just a script tag.

Comment: Does this "clean up after itself" after it executes?

Comment: Yes it does. It creates the script, stores it in a local variable, appends it to the head, then when done executing, removes the script with `head.removeChild( script );`

Comment: You can see it in the core at http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.js on line 7787

Comment: While this might not end up solving my original problem, this is the most direct answer to my question (and it's not your fault; it's my fault in phrasing).