# AJAX Progressive Output

Tags: ajax

I have a very large file which takes about 5 minutes to load. Its strictly an admin script, however I am currently building a UI for the admin to interact with. I want this script to run within the UI via AJAX. The php script currently has:

```
@apache_setenv('no-gzip', 1);
@ini_set('zlib.output_compression', 0);
@ini_set('implicit_flush', 1);
for ($i = 0; $i < ob_get_level(); $i++) { ob_end_flush(); }
ob_implicit_flush(1);
```

So it progressively outputs through the browser.

However my AJAX call (using jQuery) looks like this:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "theURL",
  success: function(data){
    $(".content").html(data);
  }
});
```

And it only outputs once the script has finished running. How can I force AJAX to use the progressive output?

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7740646/jquery-ajax-read-the-stream-incrementally

Answer (score 0):

I think that you will need to use a Web Worker (JavaScript running in the background), for example:

```
w = new Worker("demo.js");
```

where demo.js is the JavaScript in background.

Please, take a look: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webworkers.asp