# Paged JSON for infinite scrolling

Tags: json, service, local-storage, infinite-scroll

Is it possible to simulate infinite scrolling for json data. I have 10K records and most of the times, I see 50 at a stretch. But one request is sent to the service. Service sends 10K records but once I receive 50, I would like to show it in UI than wait for 10K records to load. Is there a trick I can employ to get data quick but continue to load the rest of the data into the object? Data can get into local storage too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is already answered in this question.

[jquery ajax, read the stream incrementally?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7740646/jquery-ajax-read-the-stream-incrementally)

Hope it helps.

Comment: Though not exactly what I need, I got the idea. Thanks Subhanshu :)