# How exactly does done() work and how can I loop executions inside done()?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
   $.ajax({
        url: '/api/1.0/tweets.php?username=' + username
    }).done(function (data) {
        //For loop here to do something multiple times
    )};
```

I have this piece of code. I'm trying to get something on my web page to display one at a time, but I believe the problem with my code is that `done()` is causing nothing to return until the entire for loop is finished.

1. I want to just do the ajax call to the url once.
2. I want to execute the for loop, but after each iteration, I want to return something (the ajax? I'm not sure what it's called, I'm still new to this Javascript stuff).

Maybe there's another function other than `done()`?

Comment: *done() is causing nothing to return until the entire for loop is finished* => No, the `for` loop is causing execution to not proceed until the `for` loop is finished. It's kind of what loops do. The question is meaningless without the loop and more detail (you want to return *something*?)

Comment: you can only return from a scope once. also, returning from the done callback doesn't do anything useful.

Comment: Gah I'm kind of stumped. So I have to edit my for loop then? Maybe make it a recursive call?

Comment: You say "to display one at a time". Maybe something like: http://jsfiddle.net/TkEVw/1/

Answer (score 4):

Welcome to the world of asynchronous Javascript!  One piece of advice: instead of thinking in terms of data being *returned* from functions, think in terms of functions that are executed each time some piece of data is ready.

What you need is something that will call your callback each time a piece of data is available.   A similar question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7740646/jquery-ajax-read-the-stream-incrementally), with several answers that you may find helpful.