# Watch a long PHP task with AJAX query

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to make a progress bar to watch a long PHP function (+/- 5mint).
This long PHP function read a CSV file and inserting each row in a SQL database.

Here, I'm testing with a sample PHP long function (+/- 10s).
For each loop passed, a value is incremented in db '*app_loader*'.

This function is started asynchronly with ajax call (POST).

I have make a PHP function to "watch" this sample long PHP function.
It query the database '*app_loader*' table to get fields '*loader_state*' and '*loader_total*'.
This function return (echo) json array with the '*load*' percentage and the '*ended*' state (true or false).

This function is started asynchronly with ajax call (GET) and is repeated each 500ms.

**My problem is :** The watcher ajax call work but return value only at the end of the long task ajax call.
So thats little bit boring to maked a loader bar with nothing returned when the long ajax call is started :(

Attended result of ajax watcher (each 500ms) : 1, 2, [...], 99, 100%

Thanks a lot in advance!

---

The PHP long task sample function:

```
function read_csv($name, $path)
{
    $row = 1;
    while($row < 10)
    {
        // Process (read CSV file and do something) 

        // Set progression in db
        $query = "UPDATE app_loader SET loader_state = :loader_state, loader_total = :loader_total WHERE loader_name = :loader_name";
        $query = self::$db->prepare($query);
        $query->bindValue(':loader_name', 'csv_read', \PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $query->bindValue(':loader_state', $row, \PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $query->bindValue(':loader_total', 9, \PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $query->execute();
        $query = null;

        sleep(1);

        $row++;
    }

    echo json_encode(array('task_ended' => true));
}
```

The PHP watcher function:

```
function read_csv_progress()
{
    $query = "SELECT loader_state, loader_total FROM app_loader WHERE loader_name = :loader_name";
    $query = self::$db->prepare($query);
    $query->bindValue(':loader_name', 'csv_read', \PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query->execute();
    $row = $query->fetch(\PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    $query = null;

    if($row->loader_state == $row->loader_total)
    {
        echo json_encode(array('load' => self::progress_percent(($row->loader_total), $row->loader_state), 'ended' => true));
    }else{
        echo json_encode(array('load' => self::progress_percent(($row->loader_total), $row->loader_state), 'ended' => false));
    }
 }
```

The ajax long task call function:

```
function processLongPHPTask(filename, filepath) {
    // Launch watcher
    checkProgress();

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/api/map/read/csv/global',
        data: 'name=' + filename + '&path=' + filepath,
        dataType: 'json',
        beforeSend: function (xhr) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader(
                'Authorization',
                'Bearer ' + JWT
            );
        },
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.task_ended) {
                console.log('task ended');
            }
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            console.log({
                type: 'error',
                trace: 'processLongPHPTask',
                message: {'status': xhr.status, 'error': thrownError}
            });
        }
    });
}
```

The ajax watcher call function:

```
function checkProgress() {

    // Where I call read_csv_progress() from PHP

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '/api/map/read/csv/global',
        dataType: 'json',
        beforeSend: function (xhr) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader(
                'Authorization',
                'Bearer ' + JWT
            );
        },
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.ended) {
                console.log('data process ended');
            } else {
                console.log('data progress : ' + data.load);

                // Restart the watcher each 500 ms
                setTimeout( checkProgress, 500 );
            }
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            console.log({
                type: 'error',
                trace: 'checkProgress',
                message: {'status': xhr.status, 'error': thrownError}
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Is your PHP code using Sessions? (Not necessarily specifically inside that read_csv function, but “around” it.)

Comment: Please have a look at this great answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18964123/1532004

Comment: Where is you call to read_csv_progress? I do not see it being called, so something is missing.

Comment: @RWC "read_csv_progress" is called on checkProgress() ajax function :)

Comment: @Zim84 I use just a "session_start()" in header, but I can remove it because my auth system is based on cookie ... You think start a session prevent the well run of this two simultaneous ajax queries (processLongPHPTask() & checkProgress()) ?

Comment: @BloodMotion: Where? I don't see it in your code.

Comment: @RWC Here, router make difference between a GET or POST for the same API endpoint -> url: '/api/map/read/csv/global' :)