# Stream output of command to ajax call with ServiceStack

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, servicestack

I have a ServiceStack service that executes a long-running (like 10-20 seconds) program under the hood given an input file. On the client side, a file gets uploaded to the service and the file is then passed to the executable. I have the ability to redirect the output of that executable to a stream, but when I try to send that stream to my ajax call on the client side, it doesn't start consuming until the stream is complete. I *think* I've done everything correctly to setup partial content, so I'm not sure why this isn't working (or if this is even something that's possible with ServiceStack on the server side and jQuery's ajax call on the client side). My code is below (modified slightly to remove any proprietary stuff. The same principle applies though):

```
//Service side
public async Task<HttpResult> Post(SomeProcessingRequest request) {
    var tempFile = Path.GetTempFileName();
    try {
        base.Request.Files.FirstNonDefault().SaveTo(tempFile);
        log.Info($@"Launching application");
        var ms = new MemoryStream();
        var sw = new StreamWriter(ms);
        var result = new HttpResult(ms, "text");
        //launches the app and pipes the output to the lambda (just a wrapper for Process)
        await env.LaunchApplication("myapp.exe", false, (msg) => {
            if (msg != null) {
                ms.Write(msg);
                ms.Flush();
            }
        }, (msg) => {}, () => { }, () => { throw new Exception("application failed"); }, $@"-i {tempFile}");
        log.Info($@"app complete");
        return result;
    } finally {
        try {
            File.Delete(tempFile);
        } catch(IOException ex) {
            log.Warn($@"Could not delete temp file {tempFile}");
        }
    }
}
```

And the client side ajax call:

```
this.ImportCommand = (element, event) => {
    var last_response_len = false;
    var fileInput = $('#fileInput');
    var file = fileInput.get(0).files[0];
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', file);
    $.ajax({
        url: `/*url here*/`,
        type: 'POST',
        data: formData,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success: (res) => {
            console.log("app call complete");
            self.RefreshCommand();
        },
        xhrFields: {
            onprogress: (e) => {
                console.log(e.currentTarget.response);
                var this_response, response = e.currentTarget.response;
                if (last_response_len === false) {
                    this_response = response;
                    last_response_len = response.length;
                } else {
                    this_response = response.substring(last_response_len);
                    last_response_len = response.length;
                }
                self.outputLog += this_response;
            }
        }
    });
```

So again, everything appears to work, except instead of live-streaming the output from the command, it adds it all to the stream then dumps the stream when the response comes from the server. Is what I'm trying to achieve possible with ServiceStack/jQuery? Essentially I'd like to display something along the lines of a Jenkins build log updating live.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out thanks to Petah's comment here: [jquery ajax, read the stream incrementally?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7740646/jquery-ajax-read-the-stream-incrementally/7966227#comment60263747_7975179)

The issue was that it was writing out fewer than 2048 bytes at a time. Just for kicks and giggles I created a 4096 byte array and wrote it out multiple times, with a few sleeps, and sure enough it worked as expected. I spent a lot longer on that than I should have...

Comment: I should say, I also had to write directly to Response.OutputStream instead of using the MemoryStream. I assume that's kosher.