# Render current status only on template in StreamingHttpResponse in Django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, python-2.7, python-requests

I was trying to display the status of processing to the user on the front end when I was using *StreamingHttpResponse*.

I was able to get the current status but it is being appended to the previous one.
I want the response template to contain only the current yield.

> views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import StreamingHttpResponse,HttpResponse
import time

def f1():
    x = 0
    while x<5:
        time.sleep(1)
        x = x+1
        code = """<p>{}</p>""".format(x)
        yield code


def home(request):
    return StreamingHttpResponse(f1())
```

> output in the browser

```
 <p>1</p>
 <p>2</p>
 <p>3</p>
 <p>4</p>
```

> expected output

1st: `<p>1</p>`

2nd: `<p>2</p>` instead of  `<p>1</p><p>2</p>`

3rd: `<p>3</p>` instead of  `<p>1</p><p>2</p><p>3</p>`

4th: `<p>4</p>` instead of  `<p>1</p><p>2</p>3<p></p>4<p></p>`

instead of appending the previous yield I want the template to be filled with the current yield.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't do it this way.

```
def home(request):
    return StreamingHttpResponse(f1())
```

A `StreamingHttpResponse` means you want to stream data slowly instead of one go. Now once you have placed the `<p>1</p>` on the stream, you can't just call it back and make it vanish

So you have few options on how to get it to work.

**AJAX**

You can from the page make a AJAX call which updates the latest status and you update the same using javascript

In this too you can use your existing setup with

[jQuery read AJAX stream incrementally?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7740646/jquery-read-ajax-stream-incrementally)

And then display the last line, I won't recommend this though

Next is to make a Ajax method which only returns current status

**Socket.io**

You can use the [django-socketio](https://github.com/stephenmcd/django-socketio) for the same

**Django Channels**

You can use [django-channels](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

But add `sockets` and `channels` would be a add-on complexity for your problem. So you should try to solve your with pure AJAX

Answer (score -2):

```
def f1():
    x = 1
    while x < 5:
        time.sleep(1)
        x += 1
        s = str()
        for i in range(1,x):
            s+= """<p>{}</p>""".format(str(i))
        code = s
        yield code
```

I think like this...

```
def home(request):
     for z in f1():
         return StreamingHttpResponse(z)
```

Comment: Uh, what's that? Multiple returns?