# angular how to response events from backend post api

Tags: angular, events, http-post, server-sent-events

I have a post api that produces json events. I need to consume the api in angular and react to each event, I see EventSource does not support post request. new to angular, please suggest, if there are any other alternatives or ways to consume events.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get around using xmlhttprequest onProgress.
This post was helpful -  [Difference between EventSource and XMLHttpRequest for SSE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57289483/difference-between-eventsource-and-xmlhttprequest-for-sse)